# Append Compiled Underscore Template to Document Fragment

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How do you append a compiled Underscore template to a JS document fragment?

```
var obj = {first: "Joel", last: "Spolsky"},
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    tmpl = $('#template').html(),
    compiled = _.template(tmpl, obj);

frag.appendChild(compiled);
```

When I `console.log(frag)`, I get this error:

```
`Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.`
```

I've confirmed that `compiled` contains the parsed template string; is there another step that I'm missing to make the compiled template available to the document fragment?

Comment: "compiled" usually does not denote the evaluted template, but a function which is was *compiled* to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`compiled` is a html string, not a DOM node. You cannot pass it to `appendChild`, you would have to set the `.innerHTML` property.